# pbkdf2 Salted Hash Password Verification

Tags: java, security, encryption

I've got a user database of salted hash passwords and a Java app they log into, is it better to do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `--database--` WHERE `username`= ? AND `passwordHash`= ?;
```

Then let them log in if the count is 1, or ...

```
SELECT `passwordHash` FROM `--database--` WHERE `username`= ?;
```

... Then validate it locally on the users application.

Which is more secure? - I've usually done the first way, but I keep seeing the second way pop up here and there.

For reference, the system I'm using: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55900/password-hashing-method-in-java

Comment: They'll behave the same way. Either way, you'll need to compare the hash somehow

Comment: The only security implication for the 2nd variant I see is that you may are tempted to give the error message "Invalid password" when you detect non-matching hashes. That in itself *can* be a security leak because you just revealed that the user name exists. Nothing to do with the variant itself, just a thing to keep in mind generally: error messages can potentially reveal valuable information to an attacker.

Comment: Your title talks about salted hashes, but the first query clearly doesn't work with salted passwords since you need to fetch the salt to compute the hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me the database will also have the [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29), and the application needs that to compute the hash.  Therefore you should use

```
SELECT `passwordHash`, `Salt` FROM `--database--` WHERE `username`= ?;
```

and perform the comparison at the application level.

This division of responsibility will come in handy later as you build out your authentication mechanism, e.g. if you add a [lockout](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780271%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) mechanism:

```
SELECT `passwordHash`, 
       `Salt`, 
       `LockoutStatus` 
FROM   `--database--` 
WHERE  `username`= ?;
```

If you are not using user-specific salt or a lockout then you have a potential security issue.  See the [oWASP guidance](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) on this topic.

Comment: The method I'm using only has one field for the hash, can you check it out here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55900/password-hashing-method-in-java in the code review section, so far i've not been able to get any answers

Comment: You don't always store the salt in the database. Many applications use a single salt, some combine it with the username.

Comment: Elliott, that is very true.  My advice however is consistent with established best practices.

Comment: Crizly, in your case, your APIs include the salt in the password hash itself.  Therefore your code will need to parse the hash that it obtains from the database (delimited by :) and compute the hash for comparison.